# php date insertion with conditionals

Tags: php

I want to do something like this:

If current time is > 19:30 and < 10:00 print yesterday's date [e.g. Thursday October 17th]

Else print today's date [e.g. Friday October 18th].

How can this be done with PHP?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific problem are you having?  This is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method to convert your time string into a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) object and do the comparison, like so:

```
$now = new DateTime('now');

$time1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', '19:30');
$time2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', '10:00');

if ($now > $time1 && $now < $time2) {
    echo $now->format('l F dS');
} else {
    $now->modify('-1 day');
    echo $now->format('l F dS');
}
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/55521)

Comment: Thanks Amal, that answers my question exactly!